# PyTorch Model can only recognize birds when birds are close to camera

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence, pytorch, fast-ai

**update 1**

**The easiest way to stop cropping images is: to pass in a tuple to size parameter.**

So it looks like this:

```
size=(299,299)
```

***Unfortunately, it does not solve my problem. So the question is still opening.***

---

I just trained my birds model. It works fine when I was testing it with close pictures.

But when I moved the pictures further away my camera, the model was not able to detect birds.

My guess is in this line of code

```
data = ImageDataBunch.from_folder(path=path_img, bs=48, valid_pct= 0.2, ds_tfms=get_transforms(), size=299, classes=['birds', 'others'])
```

The

> get_transforms()

and

> size=299

the function and size parameters crop my training images to centralize the images, so that birds in the images appear to be closer to the camera.

How to fix it?

[image]
[image]

Comment: don't center crop while testing. Maybe that'll help

Comment: @akshayk07 fastai seems does the crop automatically without an option of turning it off.....

Comment: You might be able to write a custom `get_transforms` function. Basically modify the input to `ds_tfms`. Maybe go through [this](https://docs.fast.ai/vision.transform.html) and there are some threads on the fastai forums about custom transforms (you can find it by searching on Google).

Comment: hi @akshayk07 thanks for your help. I have found the easiest solution to stop cropping, it does not solve the problem, but I will update my question to include the solution for stopping cropping images.

Comment: Since you trained it with center cropping, it will only work for those type of images. Assuming centre cropping generally brought the birds fairly close (filled a major part of the image with the bird).

Comment: hi @akshayk07 yep, that's what I guessed. So I have turned off cropping and trained again, the problem is still here. I think what Shai suggested might work. Once I get the code, I will train again and keep you guys updated.

Answer (score 3):

Your dataset is biased toward birds at a certain scale, i.e., their size, in pixels, span a very small range (you can verify this).
Center-cropping the images will not change that - the size of the birds (in pixels) will not change.
Therefore, your model cannot handle scale changes.

In order to overcome this limitation of the model you need to make it more scale-robust.
The simplest way to achieve this is to add **scale** augmentations to your data loader (before the crop). By introducing random scale to each training image you effectively change the size of the bird (in pixels) thus your model "sees" birds with a wider range of sizes (in pixels).

Comment: beautiful ~!  I guess this is the answer that I am looking for~!!! thanks ~! Could you elaborate your ```add scale augmentation``` with code please? It will be fantastic if the code uses Fast.Ai.

Comment: @Franva unfortunately, I am not familiar with fast.ai, it seems like you need something along the lines of [`torchvision.transforms.RandomResizedCrop`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/transforms.html#torchvision.transforms.RandomResizedCrop). You can look at the source code to see what it does exactly.

Comment: I found 3 functions in Fast.Ai, https://docs.fast.ai/vision.transform.html#get_transforms , https://docs.fast.ai/vision.transform.html#rand_resize_crop and https://docs.fast.ai/vision.transform.html#zoom_crop which one do you think is close to what you said?

Comment: @Franva it seems like the random variant of `zoom_crop` is more appropriate (it preserves the aspect ratio). However, you should pick the `scale` rage carefully to fit your actual needs. You need to check what is a "typical" bird size (in pixels) in your dataset and what you want this range to be in test time. Then you need to select `scale` to reflect this range.

Comment: hi @Shai my dataset has vast amount of bird sizes from "almost the whole picture" to "a flock of birds in sky, which is very tiny", but the place where I am going to use my bird mode is in my backyard, so the distance between camera and the fish pond will be 5-7 meters. And I saw huge birds like ibis or small birds in my backyard. >_<; it makes the problem too complicated. Am I in the wrong direction?